# Is there a way to designate a vertex group *without* weight painting?

Tags: faces, weight-painting

I have a grass particle-system that I am working on. I would like to establish the areas on my mesh where those particles should exist. Now, I know that I can use Weight Paint mode to draw out my desired area and set the Density to that group.

But is there a way that I can just choose the *faces* (not paint it out) and set *that* to become my Density? I just want to avoid the incredibly imprecise painting step that is required for that when all I want is "these four faces".

I hope that's clear; thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In edit mode select the vertices you want, the weight you want, and use *"assign"* in the data properties:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh. I was so stuck in Face Maps that I forgot about regular 'ol Vertex Groups. Thanks very much.